# How can I do a Calculation in Microsoft Excel VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

I'm 15 and I'm doing a Internship as a Developer and I've got a kinda hard exercise.

I have a Table with 3 columns, A is "Number" B is "percent" and C is "Value". The column "value" is blank and I Need to calculate the value with a macro button. I've tried this, but it was wrong because I didn´t calculate it in VBA:

```
Public Sub PushButton ()
    Range("C2:C11").Formula = "=A2*B2/100"
    Range("C2:C11").Value = Range("C1:C6).Value
End Sub
```

How do I solve this?

Comment: `function calcIntern(value1 as double, value2 as double) as double:calcIntern=(value1*value2)/100:end function`  call from sheet `=calcIntern(A2,B2)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using a defined range, you could do it with a dynamic range like this:

```
Option Explicit
Sub PushButton()

    Dim i As Long, LastRow As Long

    With ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet
        LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row 'first you need to find the last row on the active sheet

        For i = 2 To LastRow 'then iterate through all the rows starting from 2, if row 1 has headers
            .Cells(i, 3) = .Cells(i, 1) * .Cells(i, 2) / 100
        Next i
    End With


End Sub
```

If you need help understanding this code, let me know.

Edit: Explanation

Well, the first thing you must do is [Dimension](https://spreadsheeto.com/vba-dim/) all your variables, and to help that you can use the `Option Explicit`right above all your code.

I've dimensioned 1 variable for the loop and another one to find the last row with text.

To find the last row what you are actually doing is going to excel, select the last row (1048576) and the column where it will have text, in this case 1 or column "A" and then pushing ctrl+Up excel and vba will get you to the last cell with text.

To do that you use `Cells(Row, column)` instead of manually inserting row 1048576 you can just use `rows.count` and it will be the same.

Once you get the last row you just iterate with a `For i`loop meaning For a variable called `i` which equals 2 (`For i = 2`) `To LastRow` (to the last row you calculated) VBA will repeat the code in between the `For`And `Next` adding 1 number to `i` everytime the loop restarts.

In this case is just adding a number to the rows on `Cells(i, 3)` so you can modify that cell depending of its `i` value.

Comment: Yes please. And a big thank you to you , thats right the Thing i was searching for!

Comment: So do you need help understanding? What do you need to understand? Let me know and i'll edit the answer with comments on what you need.

Comment: I just started today programming with vba and don´t know anything about this ^^. The only Thing i can understand is Sub Pushbutton ().

Comment: Well then, you should first try to find a basic course of VBA on the internet, there are lots and free. Recording macros while you do thins on Excel also helps you understanding better what you can do.

Comment: I´ve already read a lot of books and Websites but they are just helping 50% , so i hoped you can tell me what is Happening in your Command.

Comment: @DominikO. i've edited my answer... Hope it explains all of it.

Comment: Yes it does. Thank you for your help .

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to question why Excel needs to calculate on demand rather than automatically like normal. Failing that there are a few options

You could change your calculation method to Manual using the following in the `ThisWorkbook` object

```
Option Explicit
Dim xlCalcMethod As XlCalculation
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    With Application
        ' Store users current method for when closing the workbook
        xlCalcMethod = .Calculation
        .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    End With
End Sub
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)
    ' Reset calculation
    Application.Calculation = xlCalcMethod
End Sub
```

and then when the button is pressed use the following code to calculate placed in a Module

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub Button_Click()
    Application.Calculate
End Sub
```

Another option to do this without looping would be:

```
Sub CalculateRange()
    Dim rng As Range

    ' Update for your Range
    With ActiveSheet
        Set rng = .Range("C2:C" & .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row)
    End With

    rng.Value2 = Evaluate(rng.Offset(0, -2).Address & "*" & rng.Offset(0, -1).Address & "/100")
End Sub
```

Finally, the way you've come up with is perfectly acceptable as `VBA`